# Spacy - lemmatization on pronouns gives some erronous output

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

lemmatization on pronouns via `[token.lemma_ for token in doc]` gives lemmatized word for pronouns as `-PRON-` , is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is in fact intended behaviour. See the documentation [here](https://spacy.io/usage/#pron-lemma):

> Unlike verbs and common nouns, there's no clear base form of a personal pronoun. Should the lemma of "me" be "I", or should we normalize person as well, giving "it" — or maybe "he"? spaCy's solution is to introduce a novel symbol, `-PRON-`, which is used as the lemma for all personal pronouns.

It might be worth noting that this convention may change in the future, as spaCy moves towards better compatibility with the [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.org/) format.

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by "no clear base form of a personal pronoun". To me it feels rather intuitive to change "me", to "I", just as "whom" to "who", or in German "dich" to "du", in Spanish "ti" to "tú", etc. I.e., to the forms that are grammatically derived from what used to be the nominative forms in any Indo-European language. Saying that "I" is the lemma of "we" seems... very very odd. "should we normalize person as well": if we don't do it for nouns and adjectives (cause they don't have one), why should we for pronouns?

Answer (score 3):

The following piece of code may help you to eliminate the `-PRON-` from your lemmatized text in lower case.

```
[token.lemma_.lower() if token.lemma_ != '-PRON-' else token.lower_ for token in doc]
```