# Search for words in text, regardless of inflection: Python

Tags: python, list, text, nlp

I'm trying to search a given text for a specified wordlist. The code is pretty straightforward.

```
# put the words you want to match into a list
word_list = ["eat", "car", "house", "pick up", "child"]

# get input text from the user 
user_prompt = input("Please enter some text: ")

# loop over each word in word_list and check if it is a substring of user_prompt
for word in word_list:
    if word in user_prompt:
        print("{} is in the user string".format(word))
```

The problem is, when I enter the following text: *"I picked up my children in the car and they ate some pears."* it doesn't match the words *"pick up"* or *"eat"*. I imagine this is because in the text they are in the past form, and in the wordlist they are in the infinitive form. So, it will only search for exact matches and won't take into consideration inflection (verb forms, irregular verbs, etc).

Is there a way to search a text to match words from a wordlist regardless of inflection?
Thanks!

Comment: eat/ate will be difficult, for other words [stemming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) should work.

Comment: I second for stemming/lemmatization. For tense shifts such as eat/ate, you may need to either use a dictionary of common words to replace in the text, or use an NLP package that can do this automatically

Answer (score 1):

This is a Natural Language Processing task, i.e. this is a question closely related to the natural language we are working with. The question is beyond mere algorithmic questions, because the algorithm must at first "understand", or "represent" the way inflection works in the language you are using.

Those solutions work with statistical models, which means that we will not get 100% accuracy. This is just because Natural Languages are too complex to solve this in a deterministic algorithm and with 100% accuracy.

For the english language there is a Python package [LemmInflect](https://github.com/bjascob/LemmInflect) which claims to have a 96.1% accuracy on english verbs.

Using this, we can do something like:

```
import lemminflect


def find_lemmas(word_set: set, test_string: str) -> list:
    word_set = set(word_set)
    found_lemmas = []

    for word in test_string.split(" "):
        lemma_dict = lemminflect.getAllLemmas(word)
        if lemma_dict:
            # values of getAllLemmas are tuples, we need a flat set
            lemmas = {y for x in lemma_dict.values() for y in x}
            found_lemma = list(lemmas & word_set)
            if found_lemma:
                found_lemmas.append(found_lemma[0])

    return found_lemmas
```

which gives us:

```
>>> word_set = {"eat", "car", "house", "pick up", "child"}
>>> test_string = """After he ate the cake he left the 
    house and went to his car. Then he wondered whether picking up the 
    children now would really be the best idea."""
>>> find_lemmas(word_set=word_set, test_string=test_string)
['eat', 'house', 'child']
```

We can see, that `"pick up"` has not been recognised. This is because we are parsing through the test_string word by word, which destroys the structure of any composed word. So, getting those composed lemmas would need a much more sophisticated logic.

We could split up the items from `word_set` into their components, and check for the presence of each component separately. Then we would still need a logic that would be able to determine whether the occurrence of inflected forms of two components of a composed word in the `word_set` in is actually an occurrence of an inflected form of the composed word, i.e. we would need to exclude scenarios like the following:

`"She bent down to pick a penny. Then she looked up and realised she had lost a pound.`"

In this case, we would find a form of `"pick"` and also a form of `"up"`, but this would not be a form of `"pick up"`.

Answer (score 1):

As jonathan.scholbach said, what you want to do is lemmatize the words in your text.  The lemma of a word is the form of the word that you would find in the dictionary.

There is a simple way to do this with [spacy](https://spacy.io/), which would look like that:

```
import spacy

nlp=spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sent = "  I picked up my children in the car and they ate some pears.."
word_list = ["eat", "car", "house", "pick up", "child"]
doc = nlp(sent)
doc_lemma = " "
for token in doc:
    #for words without a defined lemma like pronouns, spacy returns -PRON-
    #let's capture those cases and use the form in the text: 
    if token.lemma_[0] == '-':
      doc_lemma = doc_lemma + token.text.lower() + " "
    else:
        #Put the lemmas in a string, so words like "pick up" will be found as well
        doc_lemma = doc_lemma + token.lemma_ + " "

#word_list now lookks like that:
# i pick up my child in the car and they eat some pear ..
for word in word_list:
    if word in doc_lemma:
        print(word)
#output:
#    eat
#    car
#    pick up
#    child
```

**Edit:** 
As mentioned in the comments, this solution only matches compounds only if they are directly next to each other: `pick up` is matched in  `I picked up the apple` , but not in `Did you pick her up?`

A workround for verbs + particles like `pick up`could be like that:

```
#find root (the verb) and a corresponding particle
root= None
particle = None
for token in doc:
    if token.dep_=="ROOT":
        root= token.lemma_
if token.dep_ == "prt":
    particle= token.lemma_
#if both particle and root exist in the sentence, add them together to our final string,
#so verb + particle like "pick up" is matched, even when not next to each other.
if root is not None and particle is not None:
    doc_lemma = doc_lemma + root + " " + particle
```

This workaround probably has other flaws, for example when subclauses are involved.

Comment: I edited my answer, for more, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543752/spacy-lemmatization-on-pronouns-gives-some-erronous-output).

Comment: This should not detect "`pick up"` in `"Did you pick everything up?"`, right? So both our solutions have problems with spread compounds?

Comment: Yes, i did not think about that. Let me think about that.

Comment: For compound words/phrases, such as the phrasal verb 'pick up', would we need to run some sort of n-gram?

Comment: I edited my post with a workaround using dependencies to match verb+particle phrases